# MATLAB sort(A, 'descend') returns incorrect answer

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I am trying to sort the following one-dimensional array in descending order of values:

```
109 32 29 22 22 19 15 12 12
```

I know that in this case, the array is already in descending order but I am trying to figure out why when I use `sort(A,'descend')`, MATLAB returns a new order:

```
1 2 3 5 6 4 7 8 9
```

This is no longer in descending order. This is obviously causing an error in my program whenever the array is in the correct order.

Comment: Sure about this new order? 4th element (22) can't be sorted after the 6th (19).

Answer (score 2):

That order you provided is indeed not correct but that is surely **not** MATLAB's fault.  Since your array is already in descending order, the indices of sorting should simply be enumerated from 1 up to 9.

I highly suspect that the culprit is due to you not inputting your array properly.  Furthermore, your error can't be reproduced.

This can be verified by putting this into MATLAB and examining the indices of sorting:

```
A = [109 32 29 22 22 19 15 12 12]; 
[Ai,ind] = sort(A,'descend');
```

`Ai` will be the same as the input `A` while `ind` will be enumerated from 1 up to 9 in ascending order.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You're right, my error is not reproducible. I must have made the mistake of looking at the workspace after I had already applied the new order to the original array. Debugging for hours on end apparently makes me find errors where there are none...

Comment: @neurotakuko haha no problem.